# Unable to get multicharacter field in fzf preview

Tags: shell-script, awk, cut, subshell, fzf

```bash
_select () {
  apt-cache search '' | fzf \
    --prompt='search: '\
    --marker="M" \
    --ansi \
    --layout=reverse \
    --cycle \
    --multi \
    --inline-info \
    --preview "(apt show $(echo {} | awk ' - ' '{print $1}' 2>/dev/null) 2>/dev/null)" \
    --preview-window="down:wrap:${PREVIEW_BORDER:-border-sharp}" \
    -e
}
```

the following line gives me the first field

```bash
_select | awk -F ' - ' '{print $1}'
```

I want to preview the info of the package but I need the string of characters up to ' - ', in other words, the name of the package, not de description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```bash
--preview "apt show {1} 2>/dev/null"
```